# How to customize single member's entry title in buddypress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to customize title of single member's page in buddypress. This is what usually goes into entry-title div in other pages in Wordpress. Could someone tell me where to find this part of code? I've already copied wp-content/plugins/buddypress/bp-templates/bp-legacy/buddypress/members into my child theme.

Thank you in advance for answers

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by title, but this is the file to adjust in your child theme:

buddypress\bp-templates\bp-legacy\buddypress\members\single\member-header.php